# How to swap an element in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to swap the first element in a list with the third element in the array (***not*** ArrayList) so that:

```
vector = {23, 42, 3, 42, 6};
```

will become:

```
vector = {3, 42, 23, 42, 6};
```

I have tried writing into my code:

```
int temp = vector[0];
vector[0] = vector[2];
vector[2] = temp;
```

This is my code in BlueJ:

```
public class Lab1
{
 public static void main( String args[] ) {
    new Lab1().run();
}

int[] vector = {23, 42, 3, 42, 6};
int temp = vector[0];
vector[0] = vector[2];
vector[2] = temp;
    
public void run() {
   System.out.println(vector[0]);
   System.out.println(vector[2]);
   System.out.println(vector[vector.length-1]);
   System.out.println(temp);
}
}
```

Can someone explain why I am getting this error coming up.
I found this solution online, but it doesn't seem to work - what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

- The name of the array isn't important - I am only doing this as an
  exercise given to me in class.
- I did not put all the vector stuff in the run() method because I am
  very new to this and it did not occur to me that that was what I
  supposed to do
- I apologise for not inserting the code into the text - I am
  relatively new to stackoverflow and lack experience with it, so I did
  not think to insert the whole body of my code as text.

Regardless - I put the 3 lines of code I was trying to put before in the run() method, and it now works.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code as text. There's no easy way to try code in an image ourselves, we can't copy snippets of it into our answers, and it won't show up in future Google searches. See: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/68587)

Comment: You're trying to assign values into a variable in the global scope. Move `vector[0] = vector[2]` inside a function and you'll see it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Also as a quick follow up, why are you not putting all that vector stuff inside the run function?

Comment: A note on your naming: calling your variable `vector` when it isn't an actual `Vector` class is a really bad idea, especially if others need to work with it (or, in this case, analyse it so they can help you). Name your variables after what role they play in the algorithm you're implementing, not after the data structure they represent. Also, [don't show pictures of code, show code](/help/how-to-ask). It might be easy to take a screenshot, but it's _much better_ to take the few more seconds to just copy the text and include it your post with proper formatting markup.

Comment: Can you share actual text rather than a screenshot? It's difficult to understand exactly what is being compiled because the white part is just floating in the air. That's probably your mistake by the way.

I assume BlueJ is creating those yellow boxes, and in this case I would agree with @Frontear, the issue is that you're putting code outside of a method, you cannot do that (simplistic statement, but true for your case).

Comment: Tip: on your next SO question, please post actual text so that people can run it/compile it themselves, and even modify it for answering. No screenshot! Same thing for error messages, stacktraces etc. It's best to just give exactly the text output you got from the compiler or runtime.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans To be honest nobody uses the `Vector` class anymore (the only reason why it still exists is for backwards-compatibility), so I don't find the name so confusing. In some contexts, it's even a pretty good name (e.g. geometric calculations).

Comment: Where it won't be an array but a Vec2, Vec3, etc. and even there, should still be named after what role it plays. We kind of settled on these conventions for a reason, and that reason is other people. Stick to the naming conventions so that everyone reading your code doesn't need to spend the time figuring out why you deviated from them, and everyone wins.

Comment: Won't start a debate, I'm just saying it's an over-statement that "vector" is a really bad name. I don't think it's a universally accepted opinion, or that it's true in all situations. It really depends what the method does. Say a method sorts an array, I prefer calling the array `arr` than `arrayToBeSorted`, because it's already blatantly obvious from the signature ie. `<T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] arr)`. Say a method rotates a vector by a certain angle, again `void rotate(double[] vector, double theta)` sounds ok (for simple geometry, otherwise needs more encapsulation). Anywayyy

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are assigning a variable outside **{}** block, where fields initialization is expected. Try to include the swapping in your **run** method.

```
//    int[] vector = {23, 42, 3, 42, 6}; either here
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Lab1().run();
}

public void run() {
    int[] vector = {23, 42, 3, 42, 6}; // or here
    int temp = vector[0];
    vector[0] = vector[2];
    vector[2] = temp;

    System.out.println(vector[0]);
    System.out.println(vector[2]);
    System.out.println(vector[vector.length - 1]);
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Please also consider renaming the variables as suggested by other members.

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing `int[] vector = {...}`, you don't realize it but you are instantiating an instance member (a value that is attached to an instance of your class) rather than a local variable. The syntax is valid because in the absence of `public`, `protected` or `private` before an instance (or static) member declaration, it uses package-private scope (all classes in the same package can see the declaration, but not any class outside it).

Then when you're trying to assign a value to `vector[0]`, this is where it becomes invalid. You cannot make an assignment outside of a block, unless of course this assignment is made as part of a declaration. Similarly, you wouldn't be able to do `3 + 5` or `System.out.println("hello")` outside of a block (note: a method counts as a block).

Below are some illustrations:

```
public class Test {
   static {
      System.out.println("Hello, I'll execute during class initialization since I'm a static block");
   }
   
   {
      System.out.println("Hello, I'll execute during instantiation since I'm a non-static block");
   }

   System.out.println("This does not compile, cannot put anything else than a block, method, constructor or declaration at the top level of the class");

   // though using package-private is generally discouraged, private should be the default, and things that need to be accessed are typically public because they're part of a well-designed API
   // rather than being an internal detail of the class being accessed by classes located in the same package...
   String thisIsValid = "becauseItsADeclaration";

   public void test() {
      System.out.println("Inside a method I can do whatever I want");
   }
}
```